# Is this what universal covering spaces are used for?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, covering-spaces

From the perspective of real analysis, we have:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \mathrm{tan}^{-1}(1)-\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(-1) = 2\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(1) = 2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Something I've never understood, though, is how this carries over to the complex plane. In that context, you basically have to replace line integrals with contour integrals. But doesn't that mean that we can go around the poles at $\{i,-i\}$ willy-nilly, drop some residue theorem into the mix, and end up with all sorts of different values for this integral?

I thought about this for awhile, and eventually decided that maybe this is what universal covering spaces are used for. Let $U$ denote the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{i,-i\}$. Then if we can just find a way to "choose" two points $a,b \in U$ such that $a$ "is" $-1$ and $b$ "is" $+1$, then since there's only one path from $a$ to $b$ in $U$, maybe its possible to make sense of the integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx.$$

> **Question.** Is this right? If so, I'd appreciate some more details.
>
> If not, I'd appreciate a thoughtful discussion about the 'correct' way of thinking about this.

Comment: You don't have to go all the way to the universal covering space to make sense of that integral.  Indeed, since addition of numbers is commutative, you can always define integrals of holomorphic functions as long as you go to the cover associated to the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group.

Comment: Of course what you're saying about picking lifts of $-1$ and $1$ is the same as saying "Pick a homotopy class of path from $-1$ to $1$".

Comment: "The" universal cover is not a precise formulation. It is more convenient to speak about "A" universal cover space. It is unique once you have choose base points. "The universal cover" of $(X, x_0)$ is the set of homotopy classes of paths $[x_0,x]$ with fixed end points. So if you choose say $-1$ as base point in your example, "the" universal cover space is the set of homotopy classes of paths in $C\setminus \{i,-i\}$ starting from $-1$ ending somewhere, and the fiber of $1$ gives your family of integrals.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks. I didn't know that. Is there something similar for higher-dimensional objects? E.g. Paths replaced by sheets or something like that?